# Does `winston` have `fs` module dependency even I don't use `FileTransport`?

Tags: javascript, winston

I tried to use `winston` dependency in a cordova application. I know that cordova doesn't have `fs` module so I don't use `file transport` from `winston`. But I found that the build failed with below error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/ui/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports'
 @ /Users/joeyzhao/dev/mpost/ap-ui/~/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js 10:11-24
 @ /Users/joeyzhao/dev/mpost/ap-ui/~/winston/lib/winston/transports/index.js
 @ /Users/joeyzhao/dev/mpost/ap-ui/~/winston/lib/winston.js
```

I know that `winston` doesn't support browser yet. But what I try to understand is whether `winston` core has `fs` dependency. It helps me to estimate how much work I should spend on to make `winston` to work with browser.

Below is how I use `winston`.

```
import { createLogger, format, transports } from "winston";

export const defaultTransports = {
    console: new transports.Console()
};

export const logger = createLogger({
    transports: [defaultTransports.console],
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp(),

    exitOnError: false,
    exceptionHandlers: [defaultTransports.console],
    level: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'info' : 'debug'
});
```

I am using webpack to build the code and below is the config:

```
    config: {
      devtool: isProd ? false : 'eval-source-map',
      context: sourcePath,
      target: 'web',
      watchOptions: {
        ignored: [/mobile/, /build/, /coverage/]
      },

      entry: ['./index.tsx'],

      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },

      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /^(?!.*\.generated\.ttf$).*\.ttf$/,
            use: ['css-loader', 'fontface-loader']
          },
          {
            test: /\.generated.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: './assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                  plugins: ['@extjs/reactor-babel-plugin']
                }
              },
              {
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: './assets/images/[name].[ext]'
                }
              },
              {
                loader: 'image-webpack-loader'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  camelCase: true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },

      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
        alias: {
          '@ap-components': path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'components'),
          '@ap-contexts': path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'contexts'),
          '@ap-modules': path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'modules'),
          '@ap-views': path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'views'),
        }
      },

      plugins,

      stats: {
        colors: {
          green: '\u001b[32m'
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: This depends on how you build the app. The stack clearly states that it's `file` that depends on `fs`. If you don't need file transport, prevent `file` module from being bundled.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how to prevent `file` module from being bundled? Do you mean I need to rebuild `winston`?

Comment: I wonder is it possible to require Console directly. If `transports` module is required, `fs` import is triggered whenever you're going to use it or not.

Comment: This depends on how you build the app.

Comment: @estus I am using `webpack` to build

Comment: Then this is primarily Webpack question. Winston doesn't need to be rebuilt because it's not bundled in the first place, it's Node package that contains CJS modules. You need to ignore a module. See https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/ . I suppose you could stub `fs`, etc with Webpack, too, but preventing `file` from being bundled would be a cleaner solution.